# How to reuse custom jQuery validation methods?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using jQuery validation on a number of forms in my project. Some of them have specific and tricky validation requirements, and so I've written validation methods to handle them, in the usual way:

```
    $.validator.addMethod('fancyValidationTest', function (value, element, arg) { 
           ...code... });
```

Some of these methods are needed in several of the forms in the project, and so I'm putting the method definitions into the hunks of code containing the call to the form's validator -- `$('#form_id').validate()..})` or whatever.  But this is stupid -- I end up cutting and pasting the same method into multiple places in my project, when it surely seems like I should put the methods into a single place in the project, and then have the validation code access them as needed.

But so far, no luck.  I've tried moving the method(s) into a project file that loads a bunch of other frequently-used javascript code, but this produces the not unsurprising console error `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$.validator.addMethod')`.  BTW, this is a php-based project, so the "files" containing the forms and validation code are actually getting constructed on the fly, as opposed to static .html files sitting on a server somewhere.

So: Is there a way to get all these methods into a single place and have the validation code find them?  Cut-and-paste can't be the right thing to do here; thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to get all these methods into a single place and have the validation code find them?

It's no different than any other JavaScript or client-side code.  It doesn't matter how pages are constructed, you have to include these external files on *every single page* wherever you'd want to use these scripts.  Most people just put them in the common header or footer file.  Alternatively, if they are only needed on one page, then only put them on one page.

> ... but this produces the not unsurprising console error `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$.validator.addMethod')`

Then you simply forgot to include the validation plugin, or you forgot to put it ***before*** your custom `.addMethod()` methods.

This is no different than using this plugin's `additional-methods.js` file, which also happens to contain nothing but a list of calls to `.addMethod()`.

Include jQuery, then include the plugin, then include any additional methods.

```
<!--// include jQuery //-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<!--// include the validation plugin //-->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.17.0/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<!--// optionally include the additional methods //-->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.17.0/dist/additional-methods.js"></script>

<!--// include YOUR additional methods //-->
<script src="path-to-your-methods-file.js"></script>

<!--// NOW you call .validate() and initialize plugin //-->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() { // <- ensures the HTML markup is loaded first
        $('#myform').validate({    // <- initialize plugin
            // rules, options, etc.
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Got it / thanks!  My file of methods was getting loaded in the wrong place.... #duh